# ARIMA model : How does the ARIMA model forecast?

Tags: python, time-series, azure-databricks, arima

The aim of my request is to know how the forecast function of arima model works.

here I am trying to make predictions on my monthly time serie. I know that it is stationary.
I am performing a simple ARIMA(1,0,0) with the pmdarima package like following:

```
model_auto = pm.auto_arima(df_train.values, start_p=1, start_q=0,max_p=1, max_q=0,d=0,trace=True)
```

Of course I forced it to return an ARIMA(1,0,0) in order to see how it calculates the predictions.
By hand, the calculation would be : X_t = **a***X_{t-1} + **intercept**, with **a** and **intercept** given by the model.
The length of my test df is 10 so I want to forecast 10 values. The first value I want to forecast is the value at 01/01/2021. So the X_{t-1} is the value at 01/12/2020, which is 27779546.0.

The arima model brings me the parameters : **a = 0.700, intercept = 8.204e+06.**

The forecasted value with the forecast function for 01/01/2021 is **27658114.17**.

The calculation by hand is X_t = a*X_{t-1} + intercept = X_{01/01/2021} = a*X_{01/12/2020} + intercept = 27779546.0 * 0.700 + 8.204e+06 = **27649682.2**.

So my question is : why I get two different values with the two methods? (forecasted : **27658114.17**, calculate by hand : **27649682.2**)

I would appreciate your help  Thank you!

Comment: Most likely the output parameters are rounded.  Note that the results basically agree to 3 significant figures, which is the number of significant figures in `a`.

Comment: Hi @LeviRamsey, that's right. The method **arparams()** gives a rounded value. The method **param()** gives the whole significant digits. Thank you :)